# javascript function does not execute, works only in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to manipulate `css` values using `jquery`. I want to add `width` to `.block`, using the `value` of it's child element.

Function doesn't work when page is loaded, but if I run it on `console` (chrome-dev); it works.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gauge').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).parent().css('width', text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="wrap"><span class="gauge ">70%</span></span>
    <span class="wrap"><span class=" gauge ">20%</span></span>
    <span class="wrap"><span class=" gauge ">10%</span></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Probably running js before page renders

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be working well if you set the `parents` to `display: block`:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.gauge').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).parent().css('width', text);
  }); 
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}

.wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #FEFEFE;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.wrap .gauge {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.wrap:nth-child(1) .gauge {
  background-color: red;
}
.wrap:nth-child(2) .gauge {
  background-color: blue;
}
.wrap:nth-child(3) .gauge {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="wrap"><span class="gauge ">70%</span></span>
    <span class="wrap"><span class=" gauge ">20%</span></span>
    <span class="wrap"><span class=" gauge ">10%</span></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`span`s don't have a width. It works when using floating `div`s.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gauge').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).parent().css('width', text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap" style="float:left;"><span class="gauge ">70%</span></div>
    <div class="wrap" style="float:left;"><span class=" gauge ">20%</span></div>
    <div class="wrap" style="float:left;"><span class=" gauge ">10%</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```